# Super administrator can't edit front end joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hello I did login as a super admin in the front en of joomla 2.5 I do not see any little icon to edit content... Is there a trick somewhere? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

Joomla Bakcned >> Article Manager >> Options >> Editing Layout tab

Then ensure the first 2 parameters are set to "Yes".

If so, then go to the permissions tab, then click "Super Users" and ensure the group has the correct permissions.

By the way, this if for the default Joomla articles. If you are using K2 then you will need to create a new user group within the component, add your user to that group, then give the group editing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

last UPDATE : i changed the template. I can see print and mail icon, but still not edit icon. Since I did some operation in the database the problem might come from the db, any advice of how I could fix this?

---

Thank you very much Lodder!

I did not Know about the second option, but still no icon edit, but since it display when I change the template it shows that this is a template issus. I have a 1.7 template using j! 2.5 might be the problem...